# Angular Dynamic Addition of Fields

Tags: angular

Trying to add fields dynamically, but I keep getting this error. Can someone please point to me what is causing this. Link to stackblitz below.

Click `Search` `ABC` and the searched item gets added to the form below. This searched item `ABC` should be shown in the field.

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'items -> field2'
    at _throwError (shared.ts:140)
    at setUpControl (shared.ts:36)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (form_group_directive.ts:132)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (form_control_name.ts:285)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (form_control_name.ts:212)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (provider.ts:207)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.ts:429)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (view.ts:389)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (services.ts:430)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (services.ts:391)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t36ees?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: can you help me with a background of what you trying?

Comment: @Aravind added more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're gona wana do this in template:

```
<tbody formArrayName="items">
     <tr *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
          <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
          <td><input formControlName="field1" /></td>
          <td><input formControlName="field2" /></td>
          <td><input formControlName="field3" /></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

you don't want to repeat your form array name directive for every row, so just stick it on the table body once, and you need to let angular know which index in the array it's accessing, you do that with the form group name directive, with the index as the name. this properly builds the path `items -> 0 -> field2`, whereas `items -> field2` is an invalid path as it doesn't say which item in the array, and `items` has no property `field2`, it is an array of groups that have the property.

fixed blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3sgqqx?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: That makes sense. What if field is changed from Input field to Interpolation. `{{ field1 }}`. How will this work?

Comment: not sure what you mean. `field1` is a string key for a form control. it doesn't have meaning outside of the form control context

Comment: Its replacing second `<td><input formControlName="field1" /></td>` with `<td>{{field1}}</td>`. I get it as blank, hence asking.

Comment: yea `{{field1}}` is you telling it to interpolate the value of some property `field1` on the component controller that doesn't exist.  if you want the value of the control at the key `field1` for the current group you could do..  `{{ item.get('field1').value }}` as item is referring to the current group in the array, so you're getting the field1 control and then the value